# What's wrong with my differentiation (help finding a derivative)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the equation looks a bit complicated, but the derivation itself should be straightforward. But I'm evidently getting mixed up somewhere, because my answer is wrong.
$$ \frac{\partial ({-k_{b}T \ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})))}{\partial T} $$
(where V is kept constant, hence the partial derivative)

So according to the product rule:
$$ {-k_b T} \frac{\partial ({\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})))}{\partial T} + {-k_b} ({\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}}))) $$

Then the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial ({\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})))}{\partial T} 
= \frac{\partial {(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}}))}{\partial T} \frac {1} {(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}))}
= \frac{\partial {(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})}{\partial T} 2\sinh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T}) \frac {1} {(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}))}
= \frac {\epsilon} {k_b} 2\sinh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T}) \frac {1} {(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}))}
= \frac {\epsilon} {k_b} \tanh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T})$$

So the final answer I'm getting is: 
$$ {-k_b T} \frac {\epsilon} {k_b} \tanh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T}) + {-k_b} ({\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})))
=  -{\epsilon}T \tanh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T})-{k_b} {\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})) $$

But apparently this is incorrect, and the correct answer is: 
$$ \frac {\epsilon}{T} \tanh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_b T})-{k_b} {\ln(2\cosh(\frac{\epsilon}{k_{b}T}})) $$

I'm probably making a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't seem to spot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $\frac1T $  is $-\frac1 {T^2} $ .  The rest seems fine.

Comment: Oh my God, I'm REALLY out of practice with my maths. Can't believe I forgot this. Thanks!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up,  you are doing great.